# How to get existing user data from one datastore to newly connected datastore in Openam

Tags: openam, opendj, adlds

I am using Openam12 , I have following scenario:

1. install openam12 with with embedded or external openDJ.
2. add some users/groups on this data store.
3. Add new AD LDS datastore, using ADAM configuration load openam schema to AD LDS.

I can view existing users/groups in AD LDS
reflect in in my Openam12 Console in subjects(user/groups).

now my question is since I had created a some users/gorups earlier in Openam12 using external OpenadJ/or embedded data store.

how can I get those users/groups in AD LDS, if I remove “external OpenadJ/or embedded data store. this”

i.e. how am get this data? from existing data store to newly data store.

Is it possible to get existing old data from one data store to new AD LDS data store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the goal of moving the data from OpenDJ to AD LDS.
The simplest way to move data from OpenDJ to AD LDS is to export the data in LDIF format and import in AD. This assumes that AD LDS knows the format and accepts user passwords hashed with the algorithm configured in OpenDJ.
If the goal is to have 2 identical sets of data, then I would suggest a synchronization solution like OpenIDM.

Comment: Thanks ,Ludovic ,for reply, will try to export data and import to AD LDS

Answer (score 1):

LDIF export the data from OpenDJ, and do an LDIF import into AD